# Powershell - Split a string on a character

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I've got a CSV file full of filepaths like below:

```
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Old House Farm\Images
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Quay House\Text
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Church Road\Photography
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Church Road\Reports\
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Church Road\Reports\Images
```

I want to split them on the 5th '/' character to return the following (including the last trailing '/'

```
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Old House Farm\
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Quay House\
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Church Road\
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Church Road\
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Church Road\
```

So far I've tried the following:

```
$source = $Item.Source.Split("\")[0]
```

And various other combinations of the above but can't quite get what I'm after. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
[string](Split-Path "PATH")+"\"
```

If you have `$Item.Source` then:

```
[string](Split-Path "$($Item.Source)")+"\"
```

Comment: This works - but if there are items in the list without subdirectories - they are stripped to and I'm left with just D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES. Is there a way to force it so it strips from the 5th forward slash only?

Answer (score 0):

You can split each file path on the backslash to get an array of parts. Then join a maximum of 5 parts with a backslash and append another backslash tyo that:

```
$parts = "D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Old House Farm\Images" -split '\\'
'{0}\' -f ($parts[0..[math]::Min($parts.Count, 4)] -join '\')
```

Or do this with regex:

```
"D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Old House Farm\Images" -replace '^(([^\\]+\\){1,5}).*', '$1'
```

Regex details:

```
^                 Assert position at the beginning of the string
(                 Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   (              Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
      [^\\]       Match any character that is NOT a “A \ character”
         +        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      \\          Match the character “\” literally
   ){1,5}         Between one and 5 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)                
.                 Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *              Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Result:

```
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Old House Farm\
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex version:

```bsh
$Item.Source -replace "(('[^\\]+\\){1,5}).*", '$1'
```

`[^\\]+\\` matches 1-n non-`\` followed by `\`

`{1,5}` repeat the pattern 5 times

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using `Select-String`

(Note, that the pattern uses `regex`, so you need to escape the backslash `\` with another backslash `\`)

```
$source = ($($Item.Source) | Select-String -Pattern '.+\\.+\\.+\\.+\\.+\\' -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

Output:

```
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Old House Farm\
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Quay House\
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Church Road\
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Church Road\Reports\
D:\CompanyData\REPORTS\ENQUIRIES\Church Road\Reports\
```